# Is there a @LastAccessedTimestamp in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity

I want to store the last read time in a Date column when ever someone tries to load or fetch(select query, findBy methods) a entity

I had a look at `@PostLoad` as explained [in this site](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events) . Have following questions :-

(a)Just want to know if this is safe to Update entity in `@PostLoad`

(b) Is there something like `@LastAcessedTime` in JPA similar to `@UpdateTimestamp` ?

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Data
@Entity
public class SensitiveInfo {
    @Id
    private Long id; 
    
    private String data;
    
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDate createdDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDate updationTimeStamp;

    // Is there a JPA automatic way to Update this field any time hibernate loads this entity ?
    private LocalDate updationTimeStamp;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement AOP in this case, like using custom annotation. so configure the AOP when custom annotation used in a specific function. it will trigger the AOP to update the entity. or you can config to in package level, so every function in that package call will trigger AOP to update the entity.

Comment: Hi Ari thanks for your answer, but I just want to make it work with all JPA find/get queries. Also it should also work when somebody uses HQL queries (not SQL though as it’s hard to detect). Not sure how AOP custom annotation will support this. Can you share an example if possible please.